# Local dynamic binding in common lisp

Tags: closures, common-lisp, dynamic-binding

Honnestly, I'm not sure I fully understand what it means for a binding to be "dynamic" versus "lexical". But I understand that when I use `defvar` or `defparameter`to define a binding, 1. it declares a global variable 2. the binding is declared "special", so that it can be shadowed by a new local binding, e.g.

```
(defvar *x* 3)
(defun f () *x*)
(f) ;=>3
(let ((*x* 2)) (f));=>2
```

Now, my question is, would it be possible to have a local binding(i.e. a binding that doesn't pollute the global environment) that has the same property(i.e. that can be shadowed by "outer"/"newer" bindings)?

Example:

```
(special-binding ((x 1)) (defun f () x))
(f);=>1
x;=>error, no binding in the global environment
(let ((x 2)) (f));=>2
```

I tried using `(special x)` declarations in `let` block, or `(locally (declare (special x)) ...)`, but it doesn't seem to create closures(asking for the value of the variable from a function defined that way triggers an "Unbound-Variable" error).

Comment: Closures don't capture special bindings, only lexical bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a dynamic variable only takes its value from dynamic bindings, not lexical:

```
(defun f ()
  (declare (special x))
  x)

(let ((x 1))
  ;; without this declaration, we would get an unbound variable error
  (declare (special x))
  (f))
;; => 1
```

You can achieve a default value for a local dynamic binding using `progv`:

```
(defun b ()
  (progv (if (boundp 'x) () '(x))
      (if (boundp 'x) () '(1))
    (locally (declare (special x))
      x)))

(let ((x 2))
  (declare (special x))
  (b))
;; -> 2

(b)
;; -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks, answers my question well.

Answer (score 5):

You can't capture dynamic bindings in a closure, only lexical bindings.

You need to declare the variable special in the function, so it will use the dynamic binding:

```
(defun f () 
  (declare (special x))
  x)
```

Then you need to bind the variable dynamically around the call, with:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (declare (special x))
  (f))
```

Comment: Actually, the [`special` declaration outside the `let` doesn't work](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_specia.htm).  Quoting the relevant part: "A special declaration does not affect inner bindings of a var; the inner bindings implicitly shadow a special declaration and must be explicitly re-declared to be special."  You must have tested that code with `x` previously proclaimed `special` globally, e.g. through `defvar` or `defparameter`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just going from memory, I didn't test it.